# Looking for a collection of touch (pen) friendly applications on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, tablet, touchscreen

I would like to gather everyone's knowledge to create ***a list of touch screen friendly applications*** (for tablet PC). I see many nice widgets/applications on Android or iOS that were created with touch UI in mind. For example, several of news readers, and ebook readers, not to mention the famous Angry bird game :P

Besides the standalone application, I see a lot of potential to create a touch friendly applications with the latest HTML5 technology. For example http://html5.labs.ap.org/

I see great potential how people may interact with tablet PC with touch or pen, but I don't know much application that's touch/pen friendly. When I searched online, many drawing programs showed up, but I feel there are many other use, too.

Comment: Touch screen software can be easily found with a search engine like Google, we would just be [copying the internet because your question is simple to answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/) and thus it is not feasible to come up with a list of touch screen that is more useful than what Google or any other search engine provides. Try other search terms and exclude drawing from your searches with `-draw` and `-drawing` for example and I'm pretty sure you'll find other applications and perhaps sites or articles listing them...

Comment: I don't agree with the decision. I searched Google before coming to here, because there is no comprehensive list of touch friendly applications. Furthermore, since in Superuser, there are people discuss *must have Linux* or *must have Windows* software, why can't we discuss "must have touch screen application"? I found those two posts were especially useful, it contains a lot of good information about an user experience in a particular software.

Comment: I think if we can gather a list of touch friendly application with every user's own experience, it will be beneficial to everyone who is new to Windows-based tablet PC. Thus, please reconsider to reopen this topic. If my description was not clear, feel free to edit it then reopen. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Asked it on the moderator chat, they agreed with you under the condition that it is a community wiki. (which basically means everyone can help improve the quality, nobody can gain a lot of reputation as a result).

Comment: Thanks Tom! That's great! I was thinking to have it as a community wiki, too. Thank you for asking on the moderator chat for me. I was checking there this morning, and I couldn't join the room yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching some kind of addon to extend windows' build in flick gesture feature.

Today, I found this:http://labs.karpanen.fi/tfsoft/flicks2.shtml

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[MyPaint](http://mypaint.intilinux.com/) painting with pressure-sensitive pen drawing tablets

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a productivity program. Rather, it's a fun game to play on Tablet PC. Although the game did not require touch or pen to play (just mouse is sufficient), the game actually is quite enjoyable when playing with pen on the screen.
[image]
http://www.youdagames.com/Youda-Sushi-Chef-game-info-3401